# Como hacer que reconozca los comandos "dotnet" en la terminal de VS Code?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, dotnetcore

Estimad@s compañeros, me encuentro intentando correr el comando "dotnet new console", sin embargo al intertar ejecutarlo por consola de Visual Studio, me genera el siguiente error de "comando desconocido", he rebisado las variables de entorno y se encuentran correctamente configuradas debido a que al ser ejecutado el mismo comando por la terminal (Cmd de Windows), se efectua perfectamente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al ejecutarlo por la Cmd, no aparece dicho error y funciona correctamente.
Su gentil ayuda, como puedo resolverlo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Que curioso, porque la terminal de vs code es de hecho una instancia del command prompt.

Comment: @JhonRayo99, compañero No entiendo?? a que te refieres con "instancia del command prompt"???

Comment: @Avellaneda "Instancia de command prompt" se refiere a una instancia del símbolo del sistema, es decir de _cmd_

Comment: @anythingg, Compañero, pro como resolveria el inconveniente, debido a que no se si debo declarar alguna setencia en el archivo "settings.json", del Visual; ya que este mismo problema creo que lo tengo con el compilador "gcc" que de igual manera no le capta el editor de codigo.